# Android appbar background color and (back button and more menu item icon color) conflict

Tags: android, xml

I am using the below code to define my application theme. But when I tries to add back button and menu items in appbar, icon of these button and appbar background are same. As a result these two icons remain invisible. But when I click on them it works fine.

What I am missing? I think I have massed up with some very basic concept.

```
<style name="MaterialThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#99FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/custom_toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="custom_toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>

<color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#7b7f89</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="windowBackground">#A72C32</color>
```

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TAFZ.png)

here 1. back button(white color!)
2. menu button icon (also white color)
Note: I can change the color of back button from java class. But I think it is not the right way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some screenshots demonstrating your issue ?

Comment: Are you using default android buttons or import custom button icons?

Comment: default button icons. Custom button icons works fine

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
 <style name="custom_toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/windowBackground</item>
```

to this

```
<style name="custom_toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

actually you are calling @color/windowBackground in both view for toolbar background and backbutton color

Comment: <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
I am changing the title text color not the button color!